# General Recommendation on redesigning existing sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I have already made a site in MOSS 2007. There are couple of issues with it so the company has decided to redesign the site.

Now what I want is some general recommendations as to the best possible approach for restructuring the site. What should be the first steps to move ahead. Should I start with navigation followed by groups and roles? What is the best approach to start with given above scenario.

Thanks in advance...!

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is so generalized, Answering it exactly is not possible because Design & Planning is a huge topic by itself. But it is not so different from the traditional software development practise

I would suggest you

1. Start with [Planning & Design](http://www.shareesblog.com/?p=189) the Excel sheet in the Article will allow you to get started. Filled in excel sheet will serve as a Reference through out the project.
2. See out of the Requirement you have, what can be achieved out of the Box & what needs to be developed custom. **THIS IS VERY VERY IMPORTANT STEP**
3. Check your existing Application for any code or customization that can be reused.
4. Start with a little site,review & consult with the user, change and do this iteration till completion.

Comment: exactly what I was in the middle of writing...

plus:
Try to devide the site structure to match your permission requirements... let departments have thier own sub sites.. makes much more logical sense in the long term...